# Flutter: Difference in initializing variables in a Class

Tags: class, oop, dart, flutter

Currently I'm assigning all variables through initState however I'm seeing that there is no need to assign the variables through initState as I can just assign the variable with a value directly. What is the order of these assignments and how are they different? Why and when would you choose one instead of the other?

```
class Person {
  String name = "John";

  @override
  void initState(){
  ....
  ....
  }
}
```

vs

```
class Person {
  String name;
  @override
  void initState(){
    name = "John";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the assignment takes place during construction. You might want to use this form if `name` is `final`.

In the second example, the assignment takes place when `initState` is called, which could be zero, one or more times. Presumably you are referring to the `initState` of `State<T>` which the framework calls once, after construction.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the first variable cannot be assigned dynamic content to, like `AnimationController(vsync: this)`, you have to do that in initState.

I would guess initState assigning decreases performance a little bit, because you have more options.

I'd recommend using the regular assigning of variables whenever it's possible, and using initState() only when you have to.